# React Native WebView with iOS and domStorage

Tags: ios, webview, react-native

I'm currently working on a React Native app which embed a WebView. 
The app loaded in the webview uses Dom storage. So, on Android, I must set "domStorageEnabled" props to true, otherwise my app doesn't load.

I wonder if my app can run on iOS because "domStorageEnabled" is an android only props. 
Does iOS dom storage is enabled by default when using the WebView component?

Comment: Which web view you are using? UIWebView? WKWebView?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know which one react-native uses...

Comment: @BorisVerebsky I think it's UIWebView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this at work with a Mac and I can confirm that dom storage is enabled by default on iOS WebView component.